# How can I disable VS Code's builtin Git extension?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I guess visual studio code tried to make pushing and committing easier by adding some of the git features. I really don't know how i enabled it but now every line of my code gets red because it's a change. And i don't know how to remove it. So the question is how can i remove this, i don't want any git things, i handle them using terminal.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WXfz.png)

Comment: You can't `remove/disable` your `git` extension? You can check this out for how to:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace

Comment: this isn't an extension it was a built in feature but i found how to disable it. For other people who is searching, go to settings, search for git: enabled you'll find it from there.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated in the comments, you can put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"git.enabled": false
```

Or if for some weird reason that doesn't cover everything you want, then you actually disable builtin extensions by using the `Developer: Show Running Extensions` command in the command palette, and then right-clicking and disabling the builtin git extension from there. But I doubt you'll need to do that given the above setting.

If you just want to disable diff decorations, you can put the following in your settings.json file:

```json
"scm.diffDecorations": "none"
```

Comment: To help out the noobs, like me, if you're using vscode on a per-direectory-basis, the settings.json_file can be found in the directory you use to open vscode. And praise settings.diety, this works.